# Showkeys on subbottoms in memoir not showing while using the bookmark package

Tags: memoir, subfloats, bookmarks, showkeys

When running the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage[draft]{showkeys}
%\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subbottom[A\label{fig:examplea}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subbottom[B\label{fig:exampleb}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Example A and B}
    \label{fig:examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get:
[image]

However if i uncomment the bookmark package (as below):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage[draft]{showkeys}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subbottom[A\label{fig:examplea}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subbottom[B\label{fig:exampleb}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Example A and B}
    \label{fig:examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I instead end up with:
[image]

Is there a way to show the keys on the subbottom picture while also having the bookmarks picture?

*If the way is to update from TeXlive 2016 to 2017 i'll do so in a few day's, but can't do it right now*

Comment: Is it an interaction between the `\usepackage[draft]{showkeys}` and the `bookmarks` package?

Comment: @PeterWilson same result with and without the `[draft]`  option, only the bookmark package seems to affect it

Comment: `bookmark` loads hyperref, and when `hyperref` is active `\label` inside `\subbottom` behaves differently, they actually does not use `\label` at all, so the _hook_ that `showkeys` adds inside `\label` never triggers.

Comment: @daleif So the solution would be to redefine the redifined `\label`, to let showkeys activate the _hook_?

Comment: Probably not so easy, that macro is rather complex and not well documented. I have something that works, looking to see if it can be applied simply using `etoolbox`

Comment: Hmm, more complicated than than. We just need to inject `\SK@\SK@@label{#1}}` after `\@bsphack` in the proper version of `\sf@@memsub@label`. But `etoolbox` cannot handle this because of the `#1`, trying other methods

Comment: Shorter patch added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until I find a way to make a short patch, here is something that seems to work

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{showkeys}{%
      \renewcommand*{\sf@@memsub@label}[1]{%
        \@bsphack
        \SK@\SK@@label{#1}% <-- added
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
          \string\newlabel{#1}%
          {{\@nameuse{p@sub\@captype}\@nameuse{@@thesub\@captype}}%
            {\thepage}%
            {\mem@currentlabelname\relax}%
            {\@currentHref}{}}}%
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
          \string\newlabel{sub@#1}%
          {{\@nameuse{@@thesub\@captype}}%
            {\thepage}%
            {\mem@currentlabelname\relax}%
            {\@currentHref}{}}}%
        \@esphack}
    }{}
  }{}
}
\makeatother
```

Update with a shorter patch

```
% experimental, may change
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\sf@@memsub@label}{\c{@bsphack}}{%
   \c{@bsphack}\c{SK@}\c{SK@@label}\cB\{\cP\#1\cE\}
}{ \typeout{success} }{ \typeout{failure} }
\makeatother
}
\makeatother
```