# Conflict between memoir subfloats and showkeys

Tags: memoir, subfloats, showkeys

The following works perfectly:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subbottom[A\label{fig:A}]
    {\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subbottom[B\label{fig:B}]
    {\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, if I add the `[final]` option, the label is printed in the caption of each subfigure and I get errors saying that `\sf@@memsub@label@hook` is undefined. The class file `memoir.cls` includes the following snippet:

```latex
\@ifpackageloaded{showkeys}{%
    \renewcommand\sf@@memsub@label@hook[1]{%
        \SK@\SK@@label{#1}%
     }
}{}
```

Clearly, `memoir` makes some adaptions for the `showkeys` package, but these do not work with `[final]`.

I found a thread concerning a [conflict between showkeys, subfloats and bookmark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374301/showkeys-on-subbottoms-in-memoir-not-showing-while-using-the-bookmark-package/374501), but the patches suggested there does not solve my problem.

Comment: Easiest fix: for showkeys final mode is the same as not being there at all, so just outcomment the showkeys package. A fix will be available in the next memoir release. Not sure when that will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `final` option for the `showkeys` package calls `\endinput` in the style file before it has read anything into it. Here is the top of `showkeys.sty`, with the line `(*)` in question marked:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{showkeys}
          [1997/06/12 v3.12 Show cite and label keys (DPC)]
\DeclareOption{notref}{\let\SK@ref\@empty}
\DeclareOption{notcite}{\let\SK@cite\@empty}
\let\SK@refcolor\relax
\let\SK@labelcolor\relax
\DeclareOption{color}{\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \RequirePackage{color}%
  \definecolor{refkey}{gray}{.75}%
  \definecolor{labelkey}{gray}{.75}%
  \def\SK@refcolor{\color{refkey}}%
  \def\SK@labelcolor{\color{labelkey}}}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\endinput}   <--------------------- (*)
\DeclareOption{draft}{}
\ProcessOptions
```

Thus, loading `showkeys` with the `final` option suppresses all of the behaviour of `showkeys`. In effect, the package loads, but in a totally vacuous way. Then, `memoir` gets confused here:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{showkeys}{%
    \renewcommand\sf@@memsub@label@hook[1]{%
        \SK@\SK@@label{#1}%
     }
}{}
```

because `\@ifpackageloaded{showkeys}` is technically true, *but* `showkeys` didn't define anything.

The simple solution (other than either revising `showkeys` or adding a fix to `memoir`, which may happen in due course) is to comment out the line

```
\usepackage{showkeys}
```

from your TeX file when you don't want it any more. This will have literally the same effect on your file as using the `final` option, except that `\@ifpackageloaded{showkeys}` will now be `false`.

Comment: Easier in memoir: check if `\SK@` is defined, it is defined after the `\endinput`. I just added that check to memoir. But I agree, I've never used the final option of that package, I've always outcomented in when I'm not using it.

Comment: @daleif thanks! I was assuming `memoir` wouldn't want to be changed just for this. It leads to an interesting question: where is the "bug", in `memoir`, or in `showkeys`?!

Comment: The bug is in memoir. Memoir is not using the normal `\label` macro for subfigures. So instead of asking the showkeys author to adapt to an odd choice in memoir, the solution being used here was added, it was quite easy. Just never noticed the `final` option in `showkeys`.

Comment: Very generous of you! I will edit my answer slightly...

Comment: I ended up making a package that loads `showkeys` unless `[final]` is used, so as to keep that functionality.